# How distinguish two different buttons in same event click?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

On WPF, if I have only one button click event shared for two or more (52 being more precise) is there a way to distinguish which button the event come from?

```
 private void Button_Card_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // for testing
            // it works for each button, but which one has been clicked?
            MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
        }
```

[First button object with event set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzNlm.png)

[Second button object with event set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kSrX.png)

Comment: Any particular reason why 2 buttons do the same thing?   I could understand if one were a menu item

Comment: These buttons are like selectors, click in one of them I would select some data that I'd work on it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A simple google search would have redirect you to older SO question that are _exactly_ the same. In case like this, don't post another question, instead read carefully the answers available on the other questions.

Comment: Actually I was expecting an alternative to avoid making 52 methods for each button or 52 if statments. But now I realized maybe I'm using the wrong control for that, the wrong approach. Could I make a list of clickable  controls (images, listbox with images) and use a for loop to link objects or variables to them?

Comment: @DouglasFerreira - Yes, that's a good idea. It helps keep your code strongly-typed.

Answer (score 1):

`sender` should be the clicked button, but also look at `RoutedEventArgs.Source` and `.OriginalSource`

I would also look into using `Command`s and `CommandParameter` to indicate which was clicked.

Comment: Don't answer to questions that are _clearly_ duplicates of older questions. Instead flag them as duplicates and move on. Really, we don't need massive duplication of answers on this site.